# Capture Multiple TextBox values in controller using Ember View

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

Hi I am working on a form using emberJS and this is my Application Controller

```
 App = Ember.Application.create();

 App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    appName: 'Tag Editor',
    arrayVal : ['A', 'B', 'C', 'F', 'X'],
    actions: {
    formSubmit: function() {
         console.log(this.get('views'));
    }
   }
});
```

And my templates I am using application application template, and Based on array mentioned in applicationcontroller emberview will be rendered as per App.TextView

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
    <div {{bind-attr class=":appName"}}><h1>{{appName}}</h1></div>
    {{#each arrayVal}}
     <div>
      {{view App.TextView entity=this}}
    </div>
   {{/each}}
   <div>
   <button {{action 'formSubmit'}}>Submit</button>
  </div>
</script>
```

//The above template will render all the textBoxes in the template as per the bellow template,

//My TextBoxView will contain 2 textboxes firstName and lastName

```
 <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="myentity-view">
     <div class="appTitle">{{input type=text value=firstName}}</div>
     <div class="appTitle">{{input type=text value=lastName}}</div>
 </script>
```

view of the above template

```
    App.TextView = Ember.View.extend({
        templateName: 'myentity-view'
    });
```

This will be working fine by rendering all the textBox views in the application templates by each Helper and dynamically creating all the views

//But for me in each View I want to capture all the entries of firstName and lastName of the User on clicking the formSubmit in applicationController.

In the current scenario, my arrayVal length is 5 and it will dynamically create 5 TextViews as per my code. and in each TextView there is a firstName and lastName , How can I will capture all the firstName and lastNames in Controller action

Answer (score 0):

You can access the views using `this.get('childViews')`. You may want to filter the result using some unique property in the `TextView` so that other childViews are ignored. Then you basically map the whole array and return `firstName` and `lastName`.

```
formSubmit: function() {
  var values = this.get('childViews')
    .filterBy('templateName', 'myentity-view')
    .map(function(item) {
      return {
        firstName: item.get('firstName'),
        lastName: item.get('lastName')
      };
    });
}
```

[**Here is a working demo.**](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/pinera/1/edit?html,js)